# Open npy.gz file on python

Tags: python, gzip

I want to extract the .npy file from a .gz compressed with gzip and numpy. I'm using Python 3.6:

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

f = gzip.GzipFile('mydataset.npy.gz', "r")
a = np.load(f)
```

The error found:

> raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic) OSError: Not a
> gzipped file (b'\x93N')

Comment: have you tried to open the .gz file with some other tool like gzip ? gzip magic number is `1f 8b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your file is just a `.npy` file, not a `.gz` file

From the [documentation](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html)

> The first 6 bytes are a magic string: exactly \x93NUMPY.

So remove the `.gz` extension and load it without gzip module passing the name directly as `load` supports it, you'll be fine.

After renaming:

```
a = np.load('mydataset.npy')
```